# Android BLE write and read characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an Android BLE app and this code I am using for writing message to device and also reading the response. The base code is the android ble example. Just wondering why this is working with some BLE chips and others not. Is this the right way to use write and read in BLE?

```
if(BluetoothLeService.mBluetoothGatt.getService(BluetoothLeService.UUID_SERVICE) != null){

    BluetoothGattService GattService = BluetoothLeService.mBluetoothGatt.getService(BluetoothLeService.UUID_SERVICE);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = GattService.getCharacteristic(BluetoothLeService.UUID_CHARACTERISTICS);

    if(characteristic != null) {

        uuidOK = true;
        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();

        if (((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) | (charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) > 0) {

            BluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(new byte[]{0, 10, 10});
        }

        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
            // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
            // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
            }
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to be more specific on what "doesn't work"

Comment: I get a response from the device with some texas chips but not with bluegekko ble chip.

Comment: I get a response from the device with Texas ble module but not with bluegekko ble module. Windows app work with both modules.

I am using Android bluetooth ble example code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/ 

Debug points do not come to broadcastUpdate or any onChar.. or onServ... functions.

Comment: You could try the nRF Connect app and see if you get any response. One bug in your sample code is that you might execute a write and a read in parallel, which is not allowed. You must wait for the response before you send a new request. Also some bitwise operators | should obviously be &.